# Find out how a template should be referenced in Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I have created a custom template that I am trying to render from a controller. I have placed the template in `src/MyCompany/AppBundle/Contact/contact.html.twig` and am using this line to try to bring it in:

```
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

But I get this InvalidArgumentException when loading the controller:

> Unable to find template "AppBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig" (looked
>   into: /usr/src/app/app/Resources/views,
>   /usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   /usr/src/app/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).

Is there a simple way to find out how I should be referencing this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Symfony will look in the `Resources/views` directories of your bundles to find the templates. If you need a custom path like `src/MyCompany/AppBundle/Contact` you'll have to manually register it in twig configuration in your config.yml:

```
twig:
     # ...
     paths:
        '%kernel.root_dir%/src/MyCompany/AppBundle/Contact': contact_path
```

and then use it like this:

```
return $this->render('contact_path:contact.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/templating/namespaced_paths.html)

Comment: As suggestion, use the Twig syntax `@contact_path/contact.html.twig` for Twig template names, then you'll not depend on the `symfony/templating` component and extra layers to parse it.